# Mounting Windows downloads folder onto Ubuntu and installing files from it

Tags: software-installation, mount

I am an absolute absolute novice in Ubuntu and I'm trying to install a software package I downloaded onto my Windows Downloads folder. My understanding is that for this I need to mount the Windows Downloads folder and then run the installation from there. I'm looking around guides on the internet but being such a novice, it's hard to make sense of things. Yet, I need the stupid thing to run fast for an analysis...

So far I tried creating a symbolic link to my Downloads using:
`ls -s C:/Users/<myusername>/Downloads /home/<myusername>`

And I can see it using `ls -l` but can't really change to that directory.

Then I though I maybe need to mount the folder, so I tried:

```
sudo mkdir /media/windows
sudo mount C:/Users/<myusername>/Downloads /media/windows
```

But I get an error that mount point does not exist. Can someone give me basic directions please how to mount that and install the .py setup file for my installation?

FYI, I'm on Ubuntu 18.04.5, on Windows 10.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 is EOSS or *End of Standard Support* thus off-topic here, and the only other OS you mention is windows 10 that isn't Ubuntu.  Your question isn't on-topic due to no OS mentioned that is on-topic (within *standard* support being supported by the community, of which this site is part of). Your Ubuntu 18.04 is behind on security fixes too, so upgrade it asap  (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/09/17/ubuntu-18-04-6-lts-released/ shows 18.04.6 ISO release date, but installed systems upgraded before that date).

Comment: Windows installation differs from Ubuntu installation.  You will need special attention to install Windows software on Ubuntu (like using Wine for compatibility reasons).

Comment: Here you go: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MountingWindowsPartitions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't really care that you're running an older version of Ubuntu I'm sure you have a reason if not upgrade to the latest version available. You don't necessarily need to mount the drive in-order to move the software package to your Linux machine you can do several things to accomplish your goal.

##### Option 1

Secure copy the software package to your Linux machine if it's on the same network. Open up a PowerShell terminal and type the following replace the information with your user info `PS C:\Users\youruserfolder\Downloads> scp -r .\yoursoftwarepackage user1@youripaddress:/home/yourusername`. Now go back to your Linux folder and run `ls` and you should see the software package.

##### Option 2

If you have already attached the HDD to your Linux machine run `lsblk` look for the `sdb` it should have the corresponding drive storage size, so you know that's the HDD. After you have figured that out, you'll need to mount the drive, but you need to make a directory first so run `mkdir /mnt/yourfoldername`. After that you'll want to run the following command to create your symbolic link for the HDD `sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdX#`. Once that's done run this command `sudo mount /dev/sdX# /mnt/yourfolder` At this point you should be able to run the `df -h` command and you should see the newly created mount point to access your drive. I hope this helps...